# How to use mysql with Ionic 2

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic 2.I have to manipulate Mysql data base through wampserver.I find this article :
[Using PHP and MySQL with Ionic 2](http://masteringionic2.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic-2/)

Where should I save the two .php files ? in a specific folder in C:\wamp\www\ ?

private baseURI : string  = "http://www.remote-site-address-here.suffix/";

should i replace the string by the URI of the local base ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` won't work on this, so you have to put your router url (if you are on same network) or upload php files on any hosting service and link to that on

```
private baseURI : string = "http://<URL-WHERE-YOU-HAVE-UPLOADED-FILES>/";
```

Comment: thinks a lot , i'ill try it